# What is the best practise for using a service in java threads?

Tags: java, mongodb-java, java-threads

I'm writing an application that will launch several threads - the amount varies per execution, but in general more than 5 and less than 100 - each of which will repeatedly read from a Mongo database.

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {
    private MyMongoClient myMongoClient = MyMongoClient.getInstance();

    public MyThread() {
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Document myDocument = myMongoClient.getDocumentById("id");
        Document newDocument = new Document("id": "newId");
        myMongoClient.writeDocument(newDocument);
    }
}
```

I have an existing singleton service class to query and update Mongo, and would like any advice on patterns to follow for using it in the threads?

```
public class MyMongoClient {
    private static MyMongoClient INSTANCE = new MyMongoClient();
    private myCollection; 

    private MyMongoClient() {
        try (MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(host)) {
            MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("myDatabase");
            myCollection = db.getCollection("myCollection");
        } 
    }

    public static MyMongoClient getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private Document getObjectById(String id) {
        // Implementation
    }

    private write writeDocument(Document document) {
        // Implementation
    }    
}
```

As shown, each thread will read from existing entries, but not update any of them, and will write new entries using the same service

Should each thread use the same instance of the service, or should I rewrite the service so that each thread has its own instance?

Comment: In order to manage threads the best practices is have a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor who will manage the threads based on your range at least 5 threads and maximum 100 threads

Comment: Your singleton client thing is completely weird. It's not a client at all, if just wraps a collection it reads from the database in the ctor. Given it does absolutely nothing, I see no problem with sharing it between threads. Although you're going to struggle to write anything back given that it does nothing.

Comment: Also `INSTANCE` is always `null`.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that when I copied over the code. Fixed it above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to get an error because you close your `MongoClient` in that constructor.  `MongoClient` has a built in connection pool so there's no reason to create more than one.  Create just the one and share it amongst your threads.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. 
The MongoClient should be closed after the threads have all compelted as well, so I'll change the thread constructor to include a MongoClient object, and close that after all of them have completed

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ThreadPoolExecutor`. It handles everything, you just submit task to the pool.

In my sample, `keepAliveTime=10` secs, its value depends on your requirements.

```
ExecutorService threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
            5,
            100,
            10,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()
    );
```

See the Oracle [Tutorial on the Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) framework.

Comment: How to schedule tasks is not the question. The threadsafety of the OPs client thing is the question.